# Deserializing nested json in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, json, deserialization

I'm new to json and am working on deserializing some nested json into an object.  The outer object works fine, but I'm not getting any values for the inner object.  I've tried several solutions including using list object, collections, the datacontractserializer, but nothing seems to work.  I think I'm probably missing something obvious.  Here is what I have now:

The json string looks like this:
{"type":"lookup","message":"Success","version":0.1,"user":{"loginName":"username","vendor":null}}

My code is as follows:

```
<Serializable()> Public Class LookupReturn
    Private _Type As String = ""
    Private _Message As String = ""
    Private _Version As String = ""
    Private _user As New jsonUser


    Public Property Type() As String
        Get
            Return _Type
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Type = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Message() As String
        Get
            Return _Message
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Message = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Version() As String
        Get
            Return _Version
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Version = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Userobj() As jsonUser
        Get
            Return _user
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As jsonUser)
            _user = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

<Serializable()> Public Class jsonUser
    Private _loginName As String = ""
    Private _vendor As String = ""

    Public Property loginName() As String
        Get
            Return _loginName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _loginName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property vendor() As String
        Get
            Return _vendor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _vendor = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Dim _Json As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim _Message as string = "{"type":"lookup","message":"Success","version":0.1,"user"{"loginName":"username","vendor":null}}"
Dim returnData As LookupReturn = _Json.Deserialize(Of LookupReturn)(_Message)
```

I'm geting data in the type, message, version values for the LookupReturn object, and it's returning an object for the user item, but the value for loginName is an empty string.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After working with this some more, I realized that the problem was that my nested object was not named as it should be in the Get/Set section of my code.  Because I was calling it "Userobj" instead of "user" as it was called in the jSon, the deserializer wasn't able to work properly. I changed the name to "user" and all worked well!